# Pass data to function with MAT DIALOG Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, dialog

I'm working with MAT Dialog and I'm trying to pass a variable value with the dialog's form data to a function, I'm getting the form value but no the variable value. See the diagram attached:

[image]

By pressing the button I'm doing two things, I assign the value of the task ID to a variable and open the dialog:

```
addSubtask(task){
  this.taskID = task._id;
  const dialogSubTaskRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewSubtaskDialog, {
    data{
     taskID: this.taskID,
     description: this.subtaskDescription,
     dueDate:     this.subtaskDuedate,
    }
  });

  dialogSubTaskRef.afterClosed().subscribe(data => {
      console.log("Subtask Dialog output:", data);
  }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to pass `taskID` with the Dialog's `data` but it does not show when I log `data` into the console.

How can I pass this variable value along the dialog form values to my function?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

It seems that this approach is not working:

```
const dialogSubTaskRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewSubtaskDialog, {
    data{
      taskID: this.taskID,
      description: this.subtaskDescription,
      dueDate:     this.subtaskDuedate,
    }
});
```

But this one works:

```
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

dialogConfig.data = {
    taskID: this.taskID,
    description: this.subtaskDescription,
    dueDate:     this.subtaskDuedate,
};

const dialogSubTaskRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewSubtaskDialog, dialogConfig);
```

So, in the dialog component I can do this:

```
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: AddSubTaskDialogData) {
  this.id = data.subtaskID;
}
```

And works as intented.

Comment: I'm not sure if `data.subtaskID` is set somewhere else but in your snippet above, the only data that's available is: `taskID`, `description`, `dueDate`.  Also see below answer as there might be a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try this as well... you forgot the `:` delimiter between `key`:`value`

`data`:`value`

```
const dialogSubTaskRef = this.dialog.open(AddNewSubtaskDialog, {
    data:{
      taskID: this.taskID,
      description: this.subtaskDescription,
      dueDate:     this.subtaskDuedate,
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree with @Marshal.  In your own answer, creating an instance of `MatDialogConfig` is not necessary.  See https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#sharing-data-with-the-dialog-component-